# import a module from a directory, not from the installed module

Tags: python, import

I'm working on a [Python3 project](https://github.com/suizokukan/eupompos) - let's call it *myproject* - to be installed with [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi). For some reasons, I created an entry point to my project, a script [allowing to use *myproject* as an executable script](http://as.ynchrono.us/2007/12/filesystem-structure-of-python-project_21.html) - such an executable makes the project much easier to developp.

In this executable script (see [here](https://github.com/suizokukan/eupompos/blob/master/bin/eupompos) the entire file), I wrote the following line :

```
from myproject.main import main
```

If *myproject* has **not** been installed with pip, this line loads the files stored in the *myproject* **directory**, as expected. But if *myproject* has been installed, Python will load the *myproject* modules still installed through pip.

I could change the name of the directory to avoid the problem... Is there a better way to set the source of the import ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found nothing but the usual trick with `sys.path` :

```
from myproject.main import main 
sys.path.append(os.path.join("..", "myproject"))
```